# What is a Turtle Goal?

Tags: rocket-league

While playing ranked doubles, I received 20 points for a turtle goal.

**What is a turtle goal?**

Comment: There is an achievement you should also received for it - and reading it would tell you what it does.

Comment: @n_palum the achievement appears to be unlocked on a certain map only, which the OP may not have been on when they performed the goal.

Comment: @TimmyJim Fair enough - I just recalled it being an achievement too

Comment: @n_palum that is the [Sea Turtle achievement](https://www.trueachievements.com/a223469/sea-turtle-achievement) I suppose

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you score a goal by hitting the ball while your car is upside-down (on its roof).

[image: animated GIF of a turtle goal]

Comment: I assumed the car needed to be on the ground for it to be called turtling. TIL.